# Displaying data passed from Java in a React Native component

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I was successfully able to send data from Java to React-Native using a callback that invokes an array. I can display said data in the console, however I want to be able to display it inside the react-native component itself.

This is the Java method that is supposed to get all the IP addresses connected to my wifi (Thanks to JavaPF from javaprogrammingforums.com for the code)

```
@ReactMethod
public void displayConnectedDevices(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) throws IOException {

        WritableArray array = new WritableNativeArray();

        try{
            InetAddress localhost= InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();

            for(int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
            {
                ip[3] = (byte)i;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

                if (address.isReachable(1000))
                {
                    System.out.println(address + "can be pinged");
                    array.pushString(address.toString());
                }
                else if(!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
                {
                    System.out.println(address + "this machine is known in a DNS lookup");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(address + "host name could not be resolved");
                }
            }//end of for loop

            successCallback.invoke(array);

        } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
            errorCallback.invoke((e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

This is the React-Native method where I want to display the array:

```
//Importing native java module
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
var ConnectedDevicesList = NativeModules.ConnectedDevices;

let LanScanner = () => {

const [arr, setArray]  = useState([])

  displayActiveConnections = async () => {
    ConnectedDevicesList.displayConnectedDevices( (array) => { setArray(array)}, (msg) => {console.log(msg)} );
  }

    return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.displayActiveConnections }>
              arr.map((item,index)=><Text key= {"conlist"}>{item}</Text>)
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default LanScanner
```

All the guides I found point to rendering this data on the console, but not in the actual component. What should I do if I want to display this data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to see the data in console.log?

Comment: Yes, it displays just fine. I want to render that exact data in the component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useState`. `useState` is a react hook and on getting the value from the api set the value there. Looks like the api response is an array so you can use `map` and display the `Text`

```js
export const SomeFunction{

const [arr, setArray]  = useState([])

displayActiveConnections = async () => {
ConnectedDevicesList.displayConnectedDevices( (array) => {
 setArray(array)


}, (msg) => {console.log(msg)} );
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.displayActiveConnections }>
              arr.map((item,index)=><Text key= {someId}>{item}</Text>)
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

}
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know how it works out. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: UPDATE: The above implementation gives me a syntax error: "Const declarations require an initialization value". I know I can't implement this as a class because I can't declare constants inside it. But implementing it the above way gives the error I mentioned.

Comment: change `const` to `let`

Comment: Still not working. I have updated my first post with the new code that I am using. 
I am getting: "undefined is not an object. (evaluating '_react.React.createElement')
Apologies if I am not picking up on something, but I am still rather new to this.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it to work with useState after some trial and error. This however, gives me an error that "each child should have a unique key". I have yet to fix that, but at least now I can see the data in the component (which in this case is a list of IP Addresses). Thanks to brk for his help!

```
import {NativeModules, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, ScrollView, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

import LanScannerStyle from '../Styles/LanScannerStyles';

//Declaring new instance of Java Module
var ConnectedDevices = NativeModules.ConnectedDevices;

export const LanScanner = () => {

  const [arr, setArray]  = useState([]);


  displayConnectionListFromJava = () =>  {

      //Getting the data from native module, and passing it to the arr variable with useState
      try{
        ConnectedDevices.displayConnectedDevices( (arrayResponse) => {setArray(arrayResponse), console.log(arrayResponse)} );
      }
      catch(error)
      {
        console.log(error);
      }

      //Map the arr variable and render it as text
      return(
        <View>
        {
            arr.map((items, index) => 
            <View>
                 <Text>{items}</Text>
            </View>)
        }
        </View>
      );
  };


  return(
    <ScrollView>
        <View>
            {this.displayConnectionListFromJava()}
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );

}
```